# Android bash prompt corrupt with long pwd

Tags: bash, prompt, android

I'm using bash inside [Jack Palevich's Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), run on an Android phone. The bash version is 4.2.20(1)-release, obtained from [samveen on the XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2415645).

My prompt is:

```
export PS1='\[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[01;34m\] \w \$\[\e[00m\] '
```

I think I have escaped all non-printing chars correctly with `\[` and `\]` but the prompt writes over itself and the prompt becomes corrupt making a mess of terminal input.

```
mkdir - p test/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/
cd test/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/
```

It's definitely to do with the colors as

```
export PS1='\u@\h \w \$  '
```

gives me a working prompt. How can I fix it?

Comment: you can also try a different bash binary package and/or try your question at [http://android.stackexchange.com]

Answer (score 0):

It might just be your `$TERM` environment variable, if it's not properly displayed in the program; also, check the `bashrc` file as well as a`bash_logout`file and whether or not it get sourced/called (properly?).

Try this as well:

```
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
```